# CSS make select box the same size as my input text boxes

Tags: css

I have tried a lot of different things and looked on the web but I can't figure how I can have my boxes in a form aligned and at the same size.

I am using a form and inside the form a table. The table as a class and from there I try to give width and height to my input and select with:

```
table.form-override {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.form-override tr td {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
table.form-override label {
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align:center;  
}
table.form-override input, select, option {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
table.form-override input, select {
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    border : 1px #ccc solid;
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

But of course, it is not working.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe try `table.form-override select` instead of just `select`? And can you create a Fiddle to show what is actually happening?

Comment: Yea I agree with putvande. Since you're only using `select` as your selector for the selects it might have a higher ranking selector before or after. Try changing: `table.form-override input, select, option` to `table.form-override input, table.form-override select` (no need to give `option` elements box-sizing afaik)

Comment: haha nice one. It is working now. The last thing is that it is not exactly the same size as my input, the select is a little bit smaller. Any reason why?

Comment: When you say "same size" do you mean height, width, or both?

Comment: width, there is a little retreat from the right side :(

Comment: Ok I found it, this is because I changed border-box to content-box

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS works fine - see http://codepen.io/raad/pen/FniEy

```
</style>
body, td, form {
  padding: 5px;
}
table.form-override {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background-color: #fdf;
}
table.form-override tr td {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
table.form-override label {
    padding-right: 10px;
    vertical-align:center;  
}
table.form-override input, select, option {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
table.form-override input, select {
    width: 300px;
    height: 35px;
    border : 1px #ccc solid;
    vertical-align: center;
}
</style>

<form>
  <table class="form-override">
    <tr>
      <td>Hello</td>
      <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>World</td>
      <td>
        <select>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

What you may need is a reset like [Normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Although these are used more for reducing browsers inconsistencies in default object metrics, they may help with giving different objects the same metrics.

Comment: It might work in your example, but might not work for OP. Maybe OP has got an overruling styling for `select` which makes this code not work.